# Create app page with user/group picker?

Tags: 2010, user-profile, people-picker

I need to create an app page with some multiline textboxes.

In those textboxes, user should be able to type users, and put as many users or groups in the normal sharepoint way:
domain\user1; domain\user2, etc

How can I achieve this functionality in the multiline textbox?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean the width, you just set the width of the PeopleEditor control.

```
<SharePoint:PeopleEditor Width="300" ID="myppl" runat="server" AllowEmpty="false" MultiSelect="true" />
```

Comment: this is what I was looking for.!!!!

Comment: btw, after the user has selected/typed the users, how can I know which users he typed? I meant I can do it with .Text property, but probably there is a better way to get the user id or something?

Comment: Please make a separate question of that and I'll promise to answer :)

Comment: I just did it:) http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/29610/using-the-people-picker-how-to-get-the-typed-selected-users-to-save-them-somewhe

Answer (score 2):

Could you just override the style the people/group input field to be taller?  I don't think you're going to be able to mimmic the functionality of the people picker easily.

Looking at both 2007 and 2010 person/group fields, you'd just need to apply a height property to the `.ms-inputuserfield` in your application page CSS to set a height to say 100 px.  This will mke the input box appear as a multiline field but still retain the functionality of a person group field.

Comment: this is what I want in my Application page.   http://blog.christophermichaelwebb.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/09/People-Picker-1.jpg

Comment: The larger people picker field or the larger flyout wndow?

Comment: the large people picker field.

Comment: edited response to include the CSS class of a p/g field to override to increase the size.