# Using the people picker how to get the typed/selected users to save them somewhere?

Tags: user-profile

Using the people picker how to get the typed/selected users to save them somewhere?

I already know how to create a people picker in an application page, however after the user types 10 users or groups, I need to know the ids or some important info so I can save it in an internal list or something.

I should be able to know if he typed a user or a group also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//First you should validate users (myppl is the people editor control id)
myppl.Validate();

if(myppl.IsValid)
{  
 // Get list (we will create new list item and add these people to one field of that list item)
 SPList myList = SPContext.Current.Web.GetList("site/myListURL");

 // Create list item
 SPContentType itemtype = myList.ContentTypes["MyContentType"];
 SPListItem newItem = myList.Items.Add();
 newItem["ContentTypeId"] = itemtype.Id;

 // This is where we shall gather all principals, to be added later to the list item 
 SPFieldUserValueCollection userPrincipals = new SPFieldUserValueCollection();

 foreach (PickerEntity person in myppl.ResolvedEntities)
 {
  // Add everyone to the site with full permissions 
  SPPrincipal pr = mySPWeb.EnsureUser(person.Key) as SPPrincipal;
  AddPrincipalRoleToSite(pr, SPRoleType.Administrator, myList.ParentWeb);

  // Populate userPrincipals so we can use it below
  SPUser usr = newItem.Web.EnsureUser(person.Key) as SPUser;
  userPrincipals.Add(new SPFieldUserValue(newItem.Web, usr.ID, usr.Name));
 }   

 // Finally set the value of the list item field that will contain all the users
 newItem["PersonColumnInternalName"] = ownerPrincipals;

 // All done, save item
 newItem.Update(); 
}

public static void AddPrincipalRoleToSite(SPPrincipal entity, SPRoleType role, SPWeb web)
{
    SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment(entity);
    SPRoleDefinition byType = web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(role);
    roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings.Add(byType);
    web.RoleAssignments.Add(roleAssignment);
}
```

You might be able to optimize the code within for loop (cast SPPrincipal into SPUser or something), I combined the code from few different projects of mine so it might not be 100% optimal.